# integrating with arctanh

Tags: calculus

What is the best way to integrate $\int_{0}^{v}\frac{dv}{g - Dv^2}$.  The book I'm studying uses arctanh, but it seems it would be a bit simpler by rewriting it into a form of $\int\frac{du}{a^2 - u^2}$ which results in an expression using natural logarithms?  Are they equivalent?

Comment: If you use partial fraction decomposition, then of course the resulting anti derivative is equal to the anti derivative involving  an arctanh.(Apart from a constant). Using partial fraction decomp is kind of the staple method. The question becomes, what is easier: plugging in an upper value in the arctanh or into the ln's? I have my preference here, but that's just me...The only thing I am wondering, is the function continuous on the given interval $(0,v)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are indeed equivalent. The hyperbolic trigonometric functions can be written as combinations of exponentials:

$\begin{eqnarray}\sinh(x) & = & \frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{2}\\
\cosh(x) & = & \frac{e^x + e^{-x}}{2}\\
\tanh(x) & = & \frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{e^x + e^{-x}}\end{eqnarray}$

and so logically their inverses can be written with logarithms:

$\begin{eqnarray}\sinh^{-1}(x) & = & \ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})\\
\cosh^{-1}(x) & = & \ln(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})\\
\tanh^{-1}(x) & = & \frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)\end{eqnarray}$

As to whether the integral with an arctanh function is "simpler" than the one with logarithms or not probably depends a lot on what you're using it for, and whether the respective functions make sense in the domain you're integrating over.

Comment: Thank you both!  The book I'm studying goes on to integrate this resulting expression again, so I'm guessing that leaving it in arctanh form makes it easier for the follow-on integration, rather then integrating a messy natural log expression.  I just can't find an interval where their graphs appear to be equal (that's how I was trying to see if they were equivalent).

Comment: Remember that indefinite integrals include a constant of integration, so calculating the same integral two different ways can give you results that differ by a constant, and that might be why you couldn't see the graphs as equal.